SSIS package changes
I am trying to decommission the sql server. I have package I have to decommission that. Before doing that I need to rename and wait for one week to find any problem . If now I need to delete that. So when I renamed the package and deployed it. I am finding two packages in Ssms one original and other renamed one. I need only renamed in ssms catalog. What I have missed here
I need to have only one package which is renamed one

Are these stored in msdb, in the file system or is this the project deployment model?  Can you just delete the one that you do not want?

Are they tied to jobs?  Can you just disable the jobs and not worry about renaming packages?  That is how I usually do it, then remove the packages after the jobs have been disabled for a bit.
